# How to normalize an image?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, image-processing, jupyter-notebook

So i'm trying to pre-process an image, after I did grayscaling I wanted to normalize the image, when I tried normalization the code I entered would provide me with a green picture instead of the original colors of the image, I tried the following code and another code that you can see in the screenshot above along with the result.

```
norm_image = (gray_image - np.min(gray_image)) / (np.max(gray_image) - np.min(gray_image))
plt.imshow(norm_image)
```

[image: 1]